# Launch screens may not have triggered segues. main.storyboard

Tags: xcode, launch

So I am aware that the launch screen cannot have segues, but I am getting this error under `main.storyboard` not `launchscreen.storyboard`. Anyone else have/had this problem and knows how to fix it or where I may have made a mistake?

Comment: Where is `this` problem you talk about ? Please add more information to your question

Comment: That is part of my problem, when I click on the error it does not show me where it is on the storyboard. I have many segues and view controllers so I really cannot pinpoint where there is an issue. Also that same error shows up multiple times. It says, "Launch screens may not have triggered segues. main.storyboard" in the navigator to the left. I hope this answers your question. I am new to Xcode so I'm not sure if I am getting my point across.

Comment: I figured out my problem, I believe under the file inspector in the right hand navigator, I had launch screen checked for some of my storyboards. I do not remember doing this manually, but it's something to check for if you get a similar error